# Use pipeline stage marker for autofac middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, owin-middleware

I register a per-request lifetime middleware (it has some dependecies) in autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<RequestLocaleSetter>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Then I register all autofac middleware at startup.cs

```
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(resolver.ApplicationContainer);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();
```

I can set a pipeline stage for middleware registered in startup.cs like

```
        app.Use(typeof(RequestLocaleSetter));
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAcquireState);
```

How can I do it for a certain autofac-registered middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From autofac docs:
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/owin.html#controlling-middleware-order

> If you want more control over when DI-enabled middleware is added to the pipeline, you can use the UseAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector and UseMiddlewareFromContainer extensions.
>
> ```
>  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
>  builder.RegisterType<MyCustomMiddleware>(); //... var container =
>  builder.Build();
>
>  // This adds ONLY the Autofac lifetime scope to the pipeline.
>  app.UseAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector(container);
>
>  // Now you can add middleware from the container into the pipeline //
>  wherever you like. For example, this adds custom DI-enabled middleware
>  // AFTER the Web API middleware/handling. app.UseWebApi(config);
>  app.UseMiddlewareFromContainer<MyCustomMiddleware>();
> ```